# Perfect SQL Query code to produce this kind of output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3c1oRuY8ScUcjBIQ1NCdWI3TGs/view?ts=588fde52

Tags: sql, int

I've tried so different codes in order to produce an output just like the one in the link provided at the title above. Can somebody please help me out?

[image]

Comment: What is the input? the output? the context? what did you tried? in what language?

Comment: SELECT e.first_name, e.Last_Name, e.job_id, e.Salary,
       d.department_id, d.department_name,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.department_id) as NumEmployees
FROM employees e JOIN
     departments d
     ON e.department_id = d.department_id;

This is the code that I've tried, the problem is that I can't replicate the same output that is provided in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3c1oRuY8ScUcjBIQ1NCdWI3TGs/view?ts=588fde52

Comment: @VcutMan hoping that you got everything except average i am writing a solution for average. please check the answer and hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to average over the department please use the average aggregate function to get the average by departement.

```
   SELECT e.first_name, 
    e.Last_Name, 
    e.job_id, 
    e.Salary,
    d.department_id,
    d.department_name, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.department_id) as NumEmployees,
    AVG(Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY d.department_id)  FROM employees e JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id;
```